# Find K nearest neighbors of points in DF from another DF

Tags: python, pandas, nearest-neighbor

I have a DataFrame "grid" that forms a 2D grid with nodes placed at regular intervals both in X and Y (square grid), but some of the nodes are missing from the grid. The nodes are determined by `id`, `x`, and `y`, where `x` and `y` are intergers and `id` is a string.

On the other hand, I have another DF "seeds" that contains only some of the nodes of this "square_grid". "seeds" is determined by `seed_id`, `x`, and `y`, where `x` and `y` are intergers and `seed_id` is a string.

I need to compute, for every `seed_id`, which are the `id`s of it's K nearest neigbors. For example, if a seed is placed in a region where there is no missing nodes, it will have 8 first neighbors, 16 second nearest neigbors, etc.

So, if `K=24`, I need to find the match of the `seed_id` with the `id`s of its 24th nearest neighbors.

What I have tried is the following:

I used geopandas to obtain the point geometries from their `x` and `y` coordinates, than apply a buffer that forms a circle from each `seed_id`, with the radius set to catch just the 1st nearest neigbors, (`K=8`), or all the first and second nearest neighbors (`K=24`), and so on, and then I use a spatial join (sjoin) to see which `id`s are inside that circle:

```
import geopandas as gpd

circles = seeds.buffer(2)

tbuf = circles.to_frame('geometry').reset_index().merge(
seeds.reset_index(),on='index').drop(columns='index')

match = tbuf.sjoin(grid,predicate='contains').drop(
columns = ['geometry','index_right']).drop(columns=['X','Y'])
```

This code works, but I would like to obtain the nearest neighbors without using spatial operations (the grid positions are integers) and just something like:

- In the case I only need the first nearest neighbors, then, for each seed_id, match with all the `id`s that are in the square formed by `[x-1,x+1,y-1,y+1]`.
- In the case I only need the first&second nearest neighbors, then, for each seed_id, match with all the `id`s that are in the square formed by `[x-2,x+2,y-2,y+2]`.

Any ideas?

Example of a grid with one node missing:

```
1  2  3  4
4  5  6 
7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14
```

If the DF "seeds" contains only 7 and 10, and I only need the first neighbors, then the expected outcome is:

```
7,4
7,5
7,8
7,11
7,12
10,6
10,9
10,13
10,14
```

Comment: Are you aware of that 24=16+8? So it's still the "+/-2" square what you need, just not restricted to the perimeter?

Comment: Yes, I need to apply, for each seed_id, the square +/-2 (centered in the seed_id), but I don't know how to do it

Comment: could you add some toy example to understand the problem better?

Comment: I edited to add an example